# Cannot activate the 'Python Test Explorer for Visual Studio Code' extension because it depends on the 'Python' extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-3.5

I am installing vscode Version: 1.46.0 (user setup) on windows 10,
with python 3.5 and I get this error,
i've try to uninstall the extentions I have then reinstall and restart vscode but none of it worked.
could someone help please ?

> `Cannot activate the 'Python Test Explorer for Visual Studio Code' extension because it depends on the 'Python' extension, which is not loaded. Would you like to reload the window to load the extension?`